# tptp profiling in eclipse giving an error while starting tomcat in profiling mode

Tags: java, eclipse

Error java -agentlib:JPIBootLoader=JPIAgent:server=standalone;HeapProf:allocsites=true

Answer (score 0):

1. Which version of eclipse?
2. Check the "Agent Controller" settings in Preferences. Do you use the Integrated Agent Controller? Leave it to the default settings and it works with tomcat.
3. Did you install "TPTP Profiling for Webapplications"?